# Counting up the survey results

Tags: python, python-3.x, survey

I am just a beginner at programming, and I have recently created a simple survey:

```
    survey = {}
    polling_active = True


    while polling_active:
        name = input("To take part in the survey, enter your name: ")
        anwser = input("What's your favourite computer game?  ")
        survey[name] = anwser
        repeat = input("Is there enyone else who wants to participate in the 
     survey? (yes/no):  ")

        if repeat.lower() =="no":
            polling_active = False
    number_of_users = len(servey.keys())
    print(str(liczba_uzytkownikow) + " took part in the survey!")       
    print("----------Survey results----------")
    for name, anwser in survey.items():
        print("\nName: " + imie)
print("\nFavourite game: " + anwser)
```

It isn't really complicated but I wanted to do one thing. I want to add a function or something like that which checks if any of answers repeats. How could I do this? Should I use the function or what? I want it to:
1. Count up how many answers did I get
2. Maybe create a dictionary which contains an answer and the number of times the answer was in the list of answers
3. Counts the percent of times when the answer occurs in the dictionary.

Also I just found I used to write "anwser" and not "answer"....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to find answers with more than one count:

```
from collections import Counter
print([a for a, n in Counter(survey.values()).items() if n > 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it that will tell you which answers have been said more than once:

```
seen_answers = set()
multiples = set()
for answer in list(survey.values()):
    if answer not in seen_answers:
        seen_answers.add(answer)
    else:
        multiples.add(answer)
 # multiples contains the answers that have been said more than once
```

If you just wanted to find the number of answers that have been said more than once, you could do:

```
answers = list(survey.values())
len(set(answers)) - len(answers)
```